# Not allowed to load local resource: file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, google-chrome

I am using the code below to create a link, when I click on the link in IE it's working and I'm able to open the URL but not in Chrome.

```
Test<a href='#'onClick=window.open('file:\\160.53.112.171\myTest\cons\4.1\displayData.htm','_self') >
```

Below is the error message displayed on Chrome's console.

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:file:///C:/160.53.112.171myTestcons%04.1displayData.htm in chrome.

Comment: urls use `/`, not ``\``

Comment: it's not "file:\\", it's "file://" still don't know if chrome will allow it, but having the right path should help if it will.

Comment: I tried both '\' and '/' but not working in chrome and giving the above mentioned error on console.

Comment: Did you change every \ to a / or just the file:// part?  All of them need to changed.

Comment: Try with this `file:///C:/Users/`, with `///`, not `//`.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to open a file with `FILE:\\\\` via javascript in IE. IE will not allow you to open it (which is a by default behaviour) because of some security restrictions. I have faced this IE security issue before in multiple projects. You can try changing IE security settings as given below, but its not recommended (since you cannot change each and every User's setting to change the behaviour).

Following settings works for IE 8

> In Internet Explorer, go to Tools → Internet Options → Advanced. Scroll down to the Security section and check the box for "Allow active content to run on files on My Computer".

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone landing here and working in asp.net:**

I was having the same issue (not allowed to load local resource) in every browser except IE.

My workaround was to have the anchor direct to a handler & include a query string for the path:

```
<a href='handler.ashx?file=//server_name//dir//filename.pdf' />
```

Then the handler would write the file as the response (opens up in a new tab as desired with _self):

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        if (context.Request["file"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["file"].ToString()))
        {
            try
            {
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                //whichever content type you're working with
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

                //encode the path when you set the href of the anchor, so decode it now
                string file_name = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request["file"].ToString());
                context.Response.TransmitFile(file_name);

            }
            catch { }
        }
}
```

Comment: Well, when you process the request via server, there will not be any security problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm working with an older project and they are still connecting to another server for images. I put `../handler.ashx?file=` in an `img src` and it worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

I have tried this in IE, Chrome and Firefox. It's working.

```
<a href='#'onClick=window.open('displayData.html','_self') >Test</a>
```

I am not sure, but it may be possible that your browser version affects it. Please update your browser version then try again.

Comment: when executed using tomcat server its throwing the below error on browser console : Not allowed to load local resource:file:\\160.53.112.171\myTest\cons\4.1\displayData.htm , the same when executed as normal html its working fine - @Sanjay.